# Accessing member method from a for_each cycle with pointers

Tags: c++, class, methods, foreach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

class A{
  public:
    A():n(4),d(6.6),f(2.7),s("hello my dear"){}
    ~A(){}
    void printAll()
    {
      std::cout << this->n << "\n" << this->d << "\n" << this->f << "\n" << this->s << "\n\n";
    }
  private:
    int n;
    double d;
    float f;
    std::string s;
};

int main(){
  std::vector<A*> v(100);
  //filling v ...
  std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), mem_fun_ref(&A*::printAll)); // this isn't supposed to work ?
  return(0);
}
```

I have tried many many solution, this is just the last one, none of this are working, I'm targeting a solution for C++ versions older than C++11, so I would like to avoid lambda ( also I don't have problems with make this work with lambda, my problem is only with the for_each cycle ).

For the sake of clarity and code readability i would like to avoid strange binding solution, also this solution tends to add 1 more library to the program.

So, How i can simply access a method within a for_each cycle when referring to a pointer to a custom type ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, since your vector contains *pointers*, you need `std::mem_fun`, not `std::mem_fun_ref`.

Secondly, it is `std::mem_fun`, not just `mem_fun`.

Thirdly, the proper syntax for pointer-to-member is `&A::printAll`, not `&A*::printAll`. What is that `*` doing there?

Answer (score 2):

Address of your member function is `&A::printAll`, not `&A::*printAll`.

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), mem_fun_ref(&A*::printAll)); /
//                                              ^ error here - not need this *
```

Maybe you are misleading by syntax of defining  pointer to member function type - where this asterix is necessary:

```
typedef void (A*::PrintAll)();
```

[UPDATE]
And secondary (or primary - as I understood from your comments) problem was wrong function used for calling member function on object pointer - see [AndreyT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13103741/1463922) answer for details

Comment: Address of member function *always* requires the `&` operator: `&A::printAll`.

Comment: now works, thanks, but i have never written this `%A` in `%A::*printAll`

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::mem_fun` to create a function object taking pointers.

Or use [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) if you are using C++11, if generates a function object taking pointers, smart pointers and references.

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mem_fn(&A::printAll))
```